# JCE Mediabox issue

Tags: joomla, popup, joomla2.5

Im trying to open contact form with JCE Mediabox popup. 
When I click on link then popup opens and together with that popup also opens "print properties". I cant understand where that Print properties comes. 
I have used JCE mediabox before and everything worked well (no print properties opened).

How can I see where it comes from or how to disable it? Or is this not suitable with the latest Joomla version.

I tried it on a blank site, and there are same thing. So the problem cant be on my site, I think.

I just made blank site for show the problem. Maybe someone can understands wheres the problem. [Heres link](http://weblabor.eu/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a script just before `</body>` tag.which opens the print popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.print();</script>
```

Most probabely it will be in component.php of your current template folder.

like `joomla root->templates->your_template->component.php`

May this will solve your problem.